# Model performance metrics

Tags: training, categorical-data, performance, metric

I have a dataset with multiple numeric input values and a categorical output. How can I measure model performance with different algorithms. As the results are categorical, we can not obtain r squared or mean square error ect... but I have the accuracy values as performance metrics. What else can be used to measure model performances when the result is categorical?

Comment: what model(s)? Binary or multiclass?

Comment: Multiclass categorical outputs. Algorithms are logistic reg, random forest, naive bayes, xgboost. neural networks